Böhm's theorem for more than two terms
Böhm's theorem says that for two distinct normal lambda terms $A$ and $B$, and two arbitrary terms $U$ and $V$, there exists a term $X$ such that $XA=U$ and $XB=V$.
One obvious extension is increasing the number of terms that $X$ can identify, from $2$ to any (finite) amount. $X$ would be defined as follows: $XA_n=U_n$, where each $A_i$ is a distinct normal lambda term, and each $U_i$ is an arbitrary term.
An even greater extension would be an $X$ that can discriminate every normal lambda term. For each unique normal lambda term $T_n$, $T_n$ has a unique number $q_n$. $X$ is then defined as $XT_n=q_n$.
My question is whether these generalizations are possible? My intuition says that the first one is possible, since it seems like we can apply a similar strategy to the normal Böhm's theorem.  However, the second one looks almost impossible.

The first generalisation is proved by Böhm, Dezani, Peretti and Ronchi della Rocca (1979, 10.1016/0304-3975(79)90014-8).
(I bet the second one is impossible, I just havent't the time to check it right now. )
